# Basic file scanner exception/issue

Tags: java, exception, java.util.scanner

I'm working on a program for my class that asks for me to read data from a txt file, then display it back.  I have created a while loop that reads for hasNext, but I'm running into an exception. It says it's a "no such element exception" and I have no idea why.  The loop works for 5 iterations, then gives me the exception

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.io.*;

public class Project2_William_Walker
{
    public static void main (String[]args) throws IOException
    {
      File file = new File ("boarding.txt");
      Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
      DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

      String title = "Madison Kennel & Grooming";   
      String fName;
      String lName;
      String breed;
      String weight;
      String age;
      double highRisk = 20.00;




      while (inputFile.hasNext())
      {
         fName = inputFile.nextLine();
         lName = inputFile.nextLine();
         breed = inputFile.nextLine();
         weight = inputFile.nextLine();
         age = inputFile.nextLine();

         inputFile.nextLine();

         System.out.println(fName + " " + lName + " " + breed + " " + weight + " " + age);
         System.out.println();



      }
      inputFile.close();    

      System.out.println("End of Program");

   }
}
```

So in my txt file I have a list that has a first name, then a last name, followed by the breed, the weight and then the age.  Looks like this:

```
Will  
Walker  
Pug  
3  
4  

John  
Appleseed  
Retriever  
15  
7
```

..and so forth for 4 more entries.  My loop gets through the first 5 just fine, but then poops out on the 6th and final time through.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please note that it is very important to post the whole exception and its stacktrace if you have a question about an exception. So, please add that to you question.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading **6** lines in the loop, but the loop condition only checks if there is (at least) **1** line to read.

You probably have an extra blank line at the end of the input file, which causes `hasNext()` to return `true` after reading in the last block of data.

You would be better to use a `for` loop the iterates 5 times, each time checking if there's a line available, and each time saving the data into an array.

Something like:

```
String[] data = new String[5];

while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
    Arrays.fill(data, null); // clear out array, in case input is short
    for (int i = 0; i < 5 && inputFile.hasNext(); i++)
        data[i] = inputFile.nextLine();

    if (inputFile.hasNext())
        inputFile.nextLine();

    System.out.println(data[0] + " " + data[1] + " " + data[2] + " " + data[3] + " " + data[4]);
    System.out.println();
}
inputFile.close();
```

Comment: *"but the loop condition only check if there's (at least) 1 line to read"* That wouldn't be a problem (but still a code smell and error prone) if the last block wouldn't contain only _five_ lines ... :P. And this *"You probably have a blank line at the end of the input file"* would solve his problem.

Comment: @Tom oops! you're right. I totally forgot about the extra checking needed. Hopefully it looks better now.

Comment: Yes, it is better :D. Too bad you missed it, because I also wrote an answer to explain OP how to fix it (since you missed that :P), but it is quite obsolete now.

Comment: @Tom your answer is pretty good (it deserved the upvote) and not obsolete. It's OK to have two answers almost the same - different ways of explaining the same thing together can be more helpful than either alone.

Comment: Thank you both for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Let's find the source of your problem. To easily do that, let's "map" your `nextLine()` calls to the file content:

```
Iteration  Code                              Read line from file

   1       fName = inputFile.nextLine();     Will
   1       lName = inputFile.nextLine();     Walker
   1       breed = inputFile.nextLine();     Pug
   1       weight = inputFile.nextLine();    3
   1       age = inputFile.nextLine();       4
   1       inputFile.nextLine();             (empty line between blocks)
   2       fName = inputFile.nextLine();     John
   2       lName = inputFile.nextLine();     Appleseed
   2       breed = inputFile.nextLine();     Retriever
   2       weight = inputFile.nextLine();    15
   2       age = inputFile.nextLine();       7
   2       inputFile.nextLine();
```

As you can see, the last statement `inputFile.nextLine()` tries to read a line from a file, but there is nothing more to read anymore, because *"7"* was the last line. So your problem is that you expect that there is *always* an empty line after a block.

A quick fix would be adding a check, like this:

```
if (inputFile.hasNextLine())
    inputFile.nextLine();
```

But this can cause trouble if there is no empty line to split two blocks and the next block starts right after the last one.

To avoid such problems in the first place, I would recommond a different file structure. You can for example use a [csv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) with a "," as the delimiter:

> Will,Walker,Pug,3,4
>   John,Appleseed,Retriever,15,7

And read it like this:

```
final String line = inputFile.nextLine(); // read a single line
final String[] items = line.split(",");  // split that line using ','
fName = items[0];
lName = items[1];
breed = items[2];
weight = items[3];
age = items[4];
System.out.println(fName + " " + lName + " " + breed + " " + weight + " " + age);
```

And to make it even better: create a model class which holds the necessary fields to represent such a line (or a block of your former file style) and let a csv reader like [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) do the parsing for you.

Comment: That was exactly my problem! Thank you so much for the help!  Mapping it out like that really helped, I'm really new to programming so with the visualization I was able to see my problem right away.